# What is the centroid of an image?

Tags: image-processing, signal-processing

I am currently reading up on image moments, and I see image centroid begin described as the center of the mass in the image but that is not very intuitive to me.

So my question is:

In the context of image analysis with image moments, what are centroids and what relevance do they have (what information do they give me,how can I repurpose them?).

Comment: is my question too broad ? what can I improve to the question ?

Comment: Imagine a mad-shaped white splodge on a black background. Now imagine the splodge was a white china plate. The centroid is where you need to put the point of a stick under the plate so it balances.

Comment: The centroid is a point obtained as a weighted average of the pixel coordinates, where the weights are the intensities. IMO, not a very useful feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid

> In mathematics and physics, the centroid or geometric center of a
>   plane figure is the arithmetic mean position of all the points in the
>   shape.

If you want to find the centroid of a group of pixels in a binary image you calculate the average coordinate. In case of a grayscale image you can use the pixels' gray values to calculate the weighted average position.

Applications: anything where you need the centroid of a shape. How do you describe the position of something in your image for example?